# Checkbox in side drop down

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one mvc code which has many check boxes and they are connected to the database. Since these check boxes are growing so my manger asked me to put all the check boxes inside drop down so that these check boxes don't take much place on the web page.

Code on controller

```
    for (var i = 0; i < model.Workstations.Length; i++)
{
    if (model.Workstations[i].Selected)
   {
       var workstation = db.Workstations.Find(model.Workstations[i].Value);
      var documentWorkstation = db.DocumentWorkstations.Create();
      documentWorkstation.Document = document;
      documentWorkstation.Workstation = workstation;

     foreach (var employee in workstation.Certificates.Where(m => 
      m.CertificateStatus.Name == "Certified" || m.CertificateStatus.Name == 
     "Pending").Select(m => m.Employee).Where(m => !m.Archived))
{

    documentWorkstation.DocumentWorkstationEmployees.Add(employee);
   }

      document.DocumentWorkstations.Add(documentWorkstation);
  }

 }

Code on View

  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Workstations, new { @class = "control-label" })

 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Workstations.Length; i++)
 {
 <div class="checkbox">
<label>
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Workstations[i].Selected)
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Workstations[i].Value)
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Workstations[i].Text)
  </label>
</div>
 }
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem is there any way to put this code in drop down section?

Comment: I believe that what you want is using `ListBoxFor`, which able to select multiple values based on an array property. Putting checkboxes inside dropdown `<option>` element has more effort than using a select multiple element.

Comment: I tried Listboxfor did not work. and <option> is good if I am not selecting data from database. but i need data from database because database is growing time to time. and if i use <option> then I have to change code all the time.

Comment: I fixed it all by my self.